# creating a POJO containing only some elements from the response

Tags: java, json, list, parsing, pojo

I'm trying to read from a JSON response using a pojo. The response has many attributes but I only need few, I created the POJO with only those attributes, but when I'm trying to read it. it fails to parse it.

JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "attr_1":1,
        "attr_2":2,
        "attr_3":3,
        "attr_4":4,
        "attr_5":5,
    },
    {
        "attr_1":10,
        "attr_2":20,
        "attr_3":30,
        "attr_4":40,
        "attr_5":50,
    }
]
```

my POJO:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyPOJO {
    @JsonProperty("attr_2")
    private int attr_2;

    @JsonProperty("attr_4")
    private int attr_4;

    public int getattr_2() { return attr_2; }
    public void setattr_2(int attr_2) { this.attr_2 = attr_2;} 

    public int getattr_4() { return attr_4; }
    public void setattr_4(int attr_4) { this.attr_4 = attr_4;} 
}
```

I only need attr_2 and attr_4, and not the others.

this is how I'm trying to read the response:

```
MyPOJO[] arr = response.readEntity(MyPOJO[].class);
```

but it fails at this step. do we really need to have all the attributes in my POJO as there are many and I need few attributes, don't want to have redundant code?

Comment: Did you try adding  "@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)"  (from Jackson) to your class?

Comment: @StefanFreitag, thanks for the suggestions, I did try that, but it didn't work. I updated the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue. I created an empty constructor and it worked. previously I had a constructor with the two needed attributes only.